# How can I access custom fields from Asana API using Python?

Tags: python, json, asana

I'm trying to pull down the values of custom fields from my Asana list. I'm using the [Official Python client library for the Asana API v1](https://github.com/Asana/python-asana).

My code currently looks like this;

```
import asana

api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client = asana.Client.basic_auth(api_key)
me = client.users.me()
all_projects = next(workspace for workspace in me['workspaces'])
projects = client.projects.find_by_workspace(all_projects['id'])

for project in projects:
    if 'Example Project' not in project['name']:
        continue
    tasks = client.tasks.find_by_project(project['id'], {"opt_fields":"this.name,this.custom_fields"}, iterator_type=None)

    for task in tasks:
        if "Example Task" in task['name']:
            print "Matching task found."
            print task['name'] + " - " + str(task['id'])
            print task['custom_fields']
            print
```

I get the output;

```
Matching task found.
Example Task - 228660596773016
[None, None]

Matching task found.
Example Task 2 - 228660596773021
[None, None]
```

The number of "None" values is equal to the number of custom fields. How can I get the key name and the value? My ultimate goal is to verify the value and update as nessesary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experimented a little and managed to reproduce the issue you're having. Can you try `opt_fields":"this.name,custom_fields`?