# Accessing optional fields using Asana Python API

Tags: python, json, api, asana

I am trying to get additional fields when making a call through Asana's Python API `Tasks.find_by_project()`. My code for the call is:

`project_tasks = Tasks(self.client).find_by_project(project_gid, opt_fields= ["name", "memberships", "gid"])`

And I am getting:

`{'id': 408541814417314, 'gid': '408541814417314', 'memberships': [{}], 'name': 'Reports - Develop quality control report to run for MES'}`

It seems like I can only access the fields that are populated by the compact task record, but I need additional fields and would like to get them without re-looping through all the tasks and getting the complete task. Oddly, it returns an empty list, but when I look at the full tasks record there are memberships for this task.

I saw this question, which seems to be similar but the given (attempted) solution doesn't work for me (I get no additional fields):
[How can I access custom fields from Asana API using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093759/how-can-i-access-custom-fields-from-asana-api-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, I had tyo work with Asana to get this figured out. `memberships` isn't callable, you have to call  `Tasks(self.client).find_by_project(project_gid, opt_fields= ["name", "memberships.section", "gid"])` or `Tasks(self.client).find_by_project(project_gid, opt_fields= ["name", "memberships.project", "gid"])` you can also apparently call `opt_expand=['memberships']` to get all of the data.

from asana:

> Thanks for your patience!
>
> We heard back from our Platform Team regarding the issue. What you are
>   experiencing is currently expected behavior, but it is not intuitive,
>   because the membership object doesn't have any data of its own.
>
> If you wanted to get the nested data, you can specify which data you
>   want opt_fields=['memberships.project', 'memberships.section'] in
>   their opt_fields request. Another option is to use
>   opt_expand=['memberships'] to get all of the data.
>
> Hope this helps! Let me know if there's anything else I can assist you
>   with.